# How to get name, number and ID from ContactsContract.Contacts in android

Tags: java, android, contacts

I get this error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column data1`

This is my code

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
        switch (reqCode) {
            case (PICK_CONTACT) :
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {


                    TextView phoneTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
                    Uri contactData = data.getData();

                    String[] mProjection =
                            {
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,   // Contract class constant for the word column name
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID, // Contract class constant for the locale column name
                            };

                    Cursor c =  getContentResolver().query(contactData,mProjection, null, null, null);

                    String contactName = "";



                    for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
                        contactName = c.getString(0);
                        Log.v("NAME OF CONTACT", contactName);
                    }




                        c.close();

                    }
                }
                //break;
        }

    }
```

When the code is as above, I get the error message I showed earlier.

However, when I change this piece of code

```
String[] mProjection =
                            {
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,   // Contract class constant for the word column name
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID, // Contract class constant for the locale column name
                            };
```

to

```
String[] mProjection =
                            {
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,

                            };
```

It works, Log displays the name.

My question here is, why does it do this?